# Boost.Preprocessor: BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM and BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM

Tags: c++, boost, macros, boost-preprocessor

My problem is best described with code:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#define SEQ (1, 2)(3, 4)

int main() {
    // this does not compile:
    // std::cout << BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, SEQ)) << std::endl;

    // this compiles with warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM_0'
    std::cout << BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, SEQ) << std::endl;

    // Output: 1
    // Expected output: None, since it shouldn't compile cout << (1, 2) << std::endl
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Hmm, thanks

```
#define SEQ ((1, 2))((3, 4))
// ...
std::cout << BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, SEQ)) << std::endl;
std::cout << BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, SEQ)) << std::endl;
std::cout << BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1, SEQ)) << std::endl;
std::cout << BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1, SEQ)) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Which is correct.
But it doesn't solve my problem, because I want to use the sequence with `BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT`, which means I can't use extra parentheses.
I want to do something like this:

```
#define DEFINE_MY_FANCY_STRUCT(NAMESPACE_SEQ, NAME, ATTRIBUTES) \
    BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT(NAMESPACE_SEQ, NAME, ATTRIBUTES) \
    \
    // other boilerplate code here, i.e. serialization with BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP or generation of spirit parsers
```

Comment: I know this is a bit late reply, but you can always write a helper macro that will add the extra parentheses. Without this macro, your specific example could be written as  BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, (BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, SEQ))) // note the added parentheses!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#define SEQ ((1, 2))((3, 4))
```

The output should be `2` since the result of `(1, 2)` is `2`.